# Returning a MySQL row which has a hyphen in the title

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL statement:

```
(SELECT car_id,firstname,surname,email,tel,postcode,add1,add2,town,county,optin-email FROM `contacts`) 
UNION 
(SELECT car_name,firstname,surname,email,tel,postcode,add1,add2,town,county,optin-email FROM `signup`)
```

Within this database is a row called `optin-email` - I cannot change the name of this row, I just wondered if there was a way to select it without making MySQL error?

Comment: try this `optin-email`

Comment: @naveengoyal - Try what?

Comment: You have to use backticks around the column name.

Comment: A database *row* doesn't have a name, a *column* does. See the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: @fancyPants - I never asked when to use them. I didn't know what was wrong... so *no* it's not a duplicate

Comment: The other question answers your problem, so it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enclose the names within `` (bact-ticks)

`Hyphens` are a big problem because if you end up mapping a column name to a variable, most languages do not like to have hyphens inside variable names.

In `MySQL`, use the back-ticks. In standard `SQL`, use double-quotes.